# Mysql replication is breaking continously for the last 3 days

Tags: mysql, replication, constraint

By using the following command the replication connection works, but it will break after 1-2 hrs:

```
mysql> STOP SLAVE;
mysql> SET GLOBAL SQL_SLAVE_SKIP_COUNTER = 1;
mysql> START SLAVE; 

mysql> SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: 10.5.61.251
                  Master_User: repusr
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: master-bin.000006
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 30468727
               Relay_Log_File: mysql-relay-bin.000002
                Relay_Log_Pos: 28727392
        Relay_Master_Log_File: master-bin.000006
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: No
              Replicate_Do_DB: 
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 1062
                   Last_Error: Error 'Duplicate entry 'fetch_task::mayo' for key 'PRIMARY'' on query. Default database: 'oladb'. Query: 'INSERT INTO cache_update (cid, created) VALUES ('fetch_task::mayo', '1487309543')'
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 28753090
              Relay_Log_Space: 30443185
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error: 
               Last_SQL_Errno: 1062
               Last_SQL_Error: Error 'Duplicate entry 'fetch_task::mayo' for key 'PRIMARY'' on query. Default database: 'ola'. Query: 'INSERT INTO cache_update (cid, created) VALUES ('fetch_task::mayo', '1487309543')'
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
             Master_Server_Id: 1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


Now after 1hrs it break again and shows 
mysql> SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: 10.5.61.251
                  Master_User: repusr
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: master-bin.000006
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 67365133
               Relay_Log_File: mysql-relay-bin.000005
                Relay_Log_Pos: 29089448
        Relay_Master_Log_File: master-bin.000006
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: No
              Replicate_Do_DB: 
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 1452
                   Last_Error: Error 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`adsyjportal`.`ads_files_notes`, CONSTRAINT `FK_A018C6425E7E37C8` FOREIGN KEY (`ads_files_id`) REFERENCES `ads_files` (`id`))' on query. Default database: 'adsyjportal'. Query: 'INSERT INTO ads_files_notes (gu_id, sender_employee_name, note, note_time, ip_address, is_approved, is_seen, is_note_send, file_status, is_viewed_by_receiver, hits, ads_files_id, sender_seat_id, receiver_seat_id, note_sending_to, sender_employee_id, created_by_user_id) VALUES ('f225fd926b84aee4a4bc2303fa1896d7', 'Srerajelatha L, Section Officer', NULL, '2017-02-17 12:06:34', '10.10.40.517', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1101, 6, 6, 7, 33, 143)'
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 66254800
              Relay_Log_Space: 30199937
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error: 
               Last_SQL_Errno: 1452
               Last_SQL_Error: Error 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`adsyjportal`.`ads_files_notes`, CONSTRAINT `FK_A018C6425E7E37C8` FOREIGN KEY (`ads_files_id`) REFERENCES `ads_files` (`id`))' on query. Default database: 'adsyjportal'. Query: 'INSERT INTO ads_files_notes (gu_id, sender_employee_name, note, note_time, ip_address, is_approved, is_seen, is_note_send, file_status, is_viewed_by_receiver, hits, ads_files_id, sender_seat_id, receiver_seat_id, note_sending_to, sender_employee_id, created_by_user_id) VALUES ('f225fd926b84aee4a4bc2303fa1896d7', 'Sreragelatha L, Section Officer', NULL, '2017-02-17 12:06:34', '10.10.40.517', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1101, 6, 6, 7, 33, 143)'
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
             Master_Server_Id: 1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is the dup key valid?  That is, does it exist on one server, but not the other?

Comment: The Percona Toolkit has a tool for validating that Master and Slave have identical data.  See if you can use it.

Comment: `SET GLOBAL SQL_SLAVE_SKIP_COUNTER = 1;` is *only* safe to use when you already know why the replication stopped, and you've already fixed the problem.  Any other use is only going to make matters worse.  You "fix" it by rebuilding the slave, which is almost certainly throwing these errors because it is already out of sync with the master.